# Problem with Date and Time Object in ormlite in android

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using ORMlite to store the date in sqlite in android. I've created a POJO class for Data 
and when i'm creating a member variable for the Time object or Date Object it is giving NullPointerException.

this is my Pojo class

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="user_prior_commitment")
public class PreferencesPriorCommitmentRowData {

    // id is generated by the database and set on the object automagically
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;
    @DatabaseField(index = true)
    int user_id;
    @DatabaseField
    String description;

    @DatabaseField
    String location;
    @DatabaseField
    Date date;
    @DatabaseField
    String start_time;
    @DatabaseField
    String end_time;
    @DatabaseField
    int lattitude;
    @DatabaseField
    int longitude;
    ...
```

And manually i created the database with this table
and in my activity i use the below code

```
DatabaseManager<DatabaseHelper> manager = new DatabaseManager<DatabaseHelper>();
DatabaseHelper db = manager.getHelper(context);
Dao<PreferencesPriorCommitmentRowData, Integer> simpleDao =
    db.getPreferencesPriordataDao();
List<PreferencesPriorCommitmentRowData>aa = simpleDao.queryForAll();
```

But before the last line it it giving Null Pointer Exception.

Kindly Help regarding this.

Comment: Can you please post the exception?

Comment: Can you please post the exception @deepak?  I'm curious what was throwing a NPE inside of ORMLite and I'd like to make sure some protection isn't warranted.

Comment: ORMLite can't store unknown class class java.sql.Time for field 'mPreferredStartTime'. Serializable fields must specify dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` type should map to a corresponding `DATETIME` type in the database. I think that should solve your problem.